# jquery validator - name attribute and nested tags

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have this form in my page:

```
<form:form id="addUnitForm" method="POST" modelAttribute="questionUnit">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="questionText">Question</label> <input type="text"
            id="questionText" class="required" value="${questionContent[0] }" /><br/>
       Answers
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${questionContentSize-1 < 0 ? 0 : questionContentSize-1 }">
            <div id="answerRow">
                <input type="text" id="questionAnswer" name="questionAnswer${i }" class="required" value="${questionContent[i] }"/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="questionAnswerCheckbox" ${answerContent.contains(questionContent[i]) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}/> 
                <input type="button" id="removeAnswer" value="x" />
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    <input type="button" value="Add answer" id="Add_answer" />
</form:form>
```

now, when I had the same form, but without name attributes (only id's) and every `input` element had the same value of `id` attribute and no `name` attribute, when I submited form only the field with `questionText` id got validated, the rest of them were not validated.

Now, I added unique names to every `input` with `id` of `questionAnswer` in my form, and everything works, so here are my 3 questions:

1. how is it, that jquery validator validated `questionText` even, if there is no `name` attribute
2. is the `name` attribute used internally by jquery validator to decide which elements should be validated?
3. why, when I have more then one row with `questionAnswer` inputs, there is an error message near first row, no matter which row I left empty?

EDIT: here it is the form code from browser

```
    <fieldset>
    <label for="questionText">Question</label> <input type="text" value="" class="required valid" id="questionText"><br>
   Answers

<div id="answerRow">
  <input type="text" class="required valid" id="questionAnswer" name="questionAnswer0">
  <input type="checkbox" id="questionAnswerCheckbox">
  <input type="button" value="x" id="removeAnswer" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
<div id="answerRow">
  <input type="text" class="required valid" id="questionAnswer" name="questionAnswer1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="questionAnswerCheckbox">
  <input type="button" value="x" id="removeAnswer" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.how is it, that jquery validator validated questionText even, if there is no name attribute

Because the element has the class `required` on it, which jQuery validate picks up.

> 2.is the name attribute used internally by jquery validator to decide which elements should be validated?

Yes it is.

> 3.why, when I have more then one row with questionAnswer inputs, there is an error message near first row, no matter which row I left empty?

Because jQuery validate cannot natively handle multiple elements with the same name (although there may be a plugin validator to handle this though) so it always assumes the error came from the first element in the document with the specified name, so puts the error there.

Comment: About first one, I had the class set up on `questionAnswer` fields also, but they weren't validated (as I said). About the second one, thiss behaviour with error message in first row happens when I have unique names assigned to elements.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML as it looks when it's rendered, not in template format.

Comment: It seems that when I make sure that `id`s of the `questionAnswer` inputs are all unique, the error messages appear in proper places, but  it is a bit inconsistent. Firstly I needed names and now I need id's